# Missing data should be on the next array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a matchmaking system where 2 players with the same level will be joined in 1 array. However, when there are 4 players with the same level, the other 2 players are disappearing. My target is to show those 2 players with the same level in another array. I provided an image below and my codes. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```js
const source = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'player1',
            level: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'player2',
            level: 1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'player3',
            level: 2
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'player4',
            level: 2
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'player5',
            level: 3
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: 'player6',
            level: 3
        },
        { // this data is missing
            id: 7,
            name: 'player7',
            level: 1 
        },
        {  // this data is missing
            id: 8,
            name: 'player8',
            level: 1
        },



        ]
        const combine = (source) => {
            return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                if (acc[curr.level] && acc[curr.level].length > 1)
                    return acc;
                if (acc[curr.level])
                    acc[curr.level].push(curr);
                else
                    acc[curr.level] = [curr];
                return acc;
            }, {})
        }
        var result = combine(source)
        var html = ""
        var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there more then one keys i.e : 2..

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            console.log("Keys " + keys[i])
            //loop through json array
            result[keys[i]].forEach(function (val, index) {
                //check if index value is `0`..change name.
                var ids = index == 0 ? "id[]" : "idside[]"
                var name = index == 0 ? "name[]" : "nameside[]"
                var levels = index == 0 ? "level[]" : "levelside[]"
                html += `<input type="text" name="${ids}" value="${val.id}">
            <input type="text" name="${name}" value="${val.name}">
            <input type="text" name="${levels}" value="${val.level}">`
            })
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

        console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: If there should be a fourth array, what should be the key of the fourth array in the `result` object?

Comment: Hi, according to your updated json you can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/azLfnb25/) .

Comment: @Swati Hello, can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer? Thank you. Perfectly working <3

Comment: You can answer your own question ^^

Comment: I'll do that then. <3 Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Problem is on these two lines

```js
if (acc[curr.level] && acc[curr.level].length > 1)
  return acc;
```

If there already is level 1 in acc and has two or more players, you just skip all other level 1 players.

My solution, even though probably bit slower, would be to sort and group the input data based on level and then push pairs into an array.

Comment: Yes, you are right,you was faster than me)

Comment: Hello thank you for replying

I am trying a different approach, it shows now the hidden players with the same level. However, my textbox data is undefined.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rain0221/fx5r8sqw/  

Any guide on how can it make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Target achieved. Super thanks to: Swati. Also, thank you for your suggestions.

```js
const source = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'player1',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'player2',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'player3',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'player4',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'player5',
    level: 3
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'player6',
    level: 3
  },
  { // this data is missing
    id: 7,
    name: 'player7',
    level: 1
  },
  { // this data is missing
    id: 8,
    name: 'player8',
    level: 1
  },



]
const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level]) {
      const levelArr = acc[curr.level];
      const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
      if (last.length === 2) {
        levelArr.push([curr])
      } else {
        last.push(curr);
      }
    } else {
      acc[curr.level] = [
        [curr]
      ];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
};
var result = combine(source)
var html = ""
var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there more then one keys i.e : 2..

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {

    val.forEach(function(value, index) {
      var ids = index == 0 ? "id[]" : "idside[]"
      var name = index == 0 ? "name[]" : "nameside[]"
      var levels = index == 0 ? "level[]" : "levelside[]"
      html += `<input type="text" name="${ids}" value="${value.id}"> <input type="text" name="${name}" value="${value.name}">
 <input type="text" name="${levels}" value="${value.level}">`
    })
  })
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```